# JQuery Images Selector event - to slideshow

Tags: jquery, image, slideshow, slidetoggle

I am New to JQuery, just started to play with it, and i have a image selector which is working great, however i am trying to turn it in to a slideshow, so it swaps the images and text every few seconds but i still want to keep the click functions on separate elements.

Can anyone Help?:

```
$ ( function () {
    $ ("a:has(img.gallery)").click(function() {
        var largePath = $ (this) .attr ("href");
        var caption = $ (this) . attr ("title");

                var image = $ ("#large-image");
                image.fadeOut('400', function () {
                                            image.attr ({ src: largePath }) ;
                                            image.fadeIn('400');
                                                    });
                    $ ("#caption1"). text (caption) ;
                    return false;
                }) ;
    });

</script>
```

Any and all help will be most appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

jquery timers plugin is quite useful, but you can always use the javascript setInterval or setTimeout functions. You should create an array of the images you want to use and cycle through them with the timers plugin or setInterval function.

Comment: Hello, 

Thanks for answering my question, Like i said i am new to JQuery and am struggling to implement the timer plugin, do you have any example codes or links that i could look at? 

Also if you could spare the time te edit my code to show me where i am going wrong it would be a great help, 
(I know its a bit cheeky to ask but i thought i would give it a shot), Thanks again  for the help.